# Creating an array of sockets using threads

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I am new-ish at Java and trying to understand sockets and threads.  I have created a mini chat program, however it uses:

```
private static Socket clientSocket = null;
private static final socketThread[] threads = new socketThread[maxClientsCount];
```

and then creates the thread by use of:

```
//code
clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
//code
for (i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++) {
    // If found create thread
    if (threads[i] == null) {
        (threads[i] = new socketThread(clientSocket, threads)).start();
        break;
    }
}
// if no available sockets available, say "too busy" and close
```

The class for the thread uses:

```
class socketThread extends Thread {
    public socketThread(Socket clientSocket, socketThread[] threads) {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        this.threads = threads;
        maxClientsCount = threads.length;
    }      

    public void run() {
        //code 
        chatproto = new chatprotocol();
        // code
    }
}
```

All the data then gets processed and passed to the chatprotocol class which handles how to interpret the input for each connection and handles how to give output to each connection.

This allows me to access to each socket using:

```
threads[i].chatproto.[insert method/variable]
```

to access each socket handler.

I have been reading maybe I should be using "implements runnable" instead, but having trouble converting my code.  Is it correct to use "implements runnable" in this case and how do I access each instance of the chatprotocol class if I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In general using "implemens runnable" is the best way to start a new thread. But the idea of this interace differs from your implementation, therefor it is obviously hard to convert the code.
The idea is to encapsul your code from the actual thread, so you are able to rerun it in an other tread for example. The problem with this is, that your have no access to your Runnable class.
One solution would be to inject every instance of your socketThread its own chatproto object. this would looks like

```
class socketThread implements Runnable {  
//code  
    chatproto = null;  
    public static socketThead (chatprotocol chatproto) {  
        this.chatproto = chatproto;  
    }  
// code  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by user3297516 "implements runnable" is always the best to start a thread. But as it is an interface you can't create the instance of it normally. To create a instance you have to create a anonymous inner class. for example:

```
    class InnerRunnable2 {
    private int countDown = 5;

    private Thread t;

    public InnerRunnable2(String name) {
    t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
    while (true) {
      System.out.println(this);
      if (--countDown == 0)
        return;
      try {
        Thread.sleep(10);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
    }
  }

  public String toString() {
    return Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": " + countDown;
  }
}, name);
t.start();
```

}
  }